# PHP json_decode backslash

Tags: php, json, server

I'm receiving a JSON string on a server, which has to be converted through json_decode. This string may contain anything. Following some hard to reproduce problems, I tried the following as a test:

```
$data = '{"client":"Test @#€%&-+()\/\\_*\""}';
$data = json_decode($data);
var_dump($data); die;
```

This returns NULL. If I delete the \\, the code works. I tried this in Google Dev Tools and it works within Javascript. How can I make it work in json_decode?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the \ in this string?  To escape or to have the literal \ char?

Comment: Using \\\ or \\\\ will successfully decode JSON string having literal backslash (`\\`) char in it.

Comment: @lolbas, already tried, also returned null. As a matter of fact, str_replace("\\\\", ...) actually didn't work at all.

AbraCadaver, sorry, forgot to mention that the string was already escaped by the sender (in this case, an Android device). So \\ is a literal \ char.

Comment: `echo $data;` before decoding and check if it really contains this what you wanted.

Comment: @MichałSznurawa I actually cut that part from the code posted here. I had three steps with several tries and var_dump amongst it. The data is just as in the code above before the json_decode

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you are experiencing with null here is caused because of double escaping: one for PHP string and one for interpreted later json. So e.g. after adding few `\` it behaves like that:

```
php > $data = '{"client":"Test @#%&-+()\\/\\\\_*\""}';
var_dump(json_decode($data));
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["client"]=>
  string(18) "Test @#%&-+()/\_*""
}
```

You can put as well your test json into file and read it, and then you will not have to worry about escaping anything as PHP string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, this is generated directly by user input. Although this case was a test, we had several problems with "special characters" when receiving data on PHP side. Since I don't have control over the input, I must find a server-side solution.